# failure in Update of sql table data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to update users details if user want to edit his/her information on our system I use following code but I couldn't be able to do it. There is no error or exception occur, even I add watch and code smoothly execute.

```
public void updateprofile()
{

    SqlConnection MySQL = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BloodDonorRegistrationConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Donor SET D_FirstName= @fn, D_LastName=@ln, D_Phone=@phn, D_City=@ct, D_Address=@add where D_Email='"+Session["UserID"]+"'", MySQL);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", TextBoxFName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln", TextBoxLName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phn", TextBoxCellNum.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ct", DropDownListCity.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", ButtonAddress.Text);
    MySQL.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MySQL.Close();
    Response.Redirect("doDashboard.aspx");
}
```

Please guide and thanks in advance.

Comment: First guess is that Session["UserID"] is not matching D_Email in any rows in your database.

Comment: Session["UserID"] is the userid/email against which user got logged in his./her account. D_Email is matching this is not issue.

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` then copy the value of the SQL command from cmd and execute it manually in the database?

Comment: no thing happen. It just pass through this point also.

Comment: My C# is a bit rusty but don't you need to quote all of your text (similar to how you quoted `Session["UserID"]`?  Can you print out `cmd` and then try the same query in a SQL session?

Answer (score 0):

`Session["UserID"]` is an object, but i think **D_Email** column in your database is of varchar type so try using `Session["UserID"].ToString()` while using in where clause.It will work....